# In Vue.js how can I know that the entire view has rendered, including AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, intro.js

According to the [Vue.js API documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) using `nextTick()` inside `mounted()` will guarantee that the entire view has rendered, but I am not sure what they mean by "rendered" in this case.

I am trying to integrate the [intro.js](http://introjs.com/) library intro Vue.js, but if I use put `introJs().start()` inside of `nextTick` like the following:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that supposedly will run only after the
    // entire view has been rendered
       introJs().start()
  })
}
```

it seems like the DOM is still not fully ready and introJs fails to show all intro steps successfully.

[Reproduction link](https://jsfiddle.net/59fo75Le/40/)

How can I know that everything is truly ready? Is there any other way to start introJs within Vue.js?

Comment: I doubt the docs are wrong, there must be something else going on. if you can create a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem, i'd be glad to help.

Comment: @EricGuan I am working on a reproduction link. Thanks

Comment: @EricGuan reproduction link ready!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `v-if`. If the condition is false, the html element will not be in document, meaning introjs can't find it. In the browser dev tools, if you look at the component when the `v-if` condition is false, you would see an html comment, `<!-- -->`.

The easy fix is to use `v-show`. This way the element will be in document, introjs can find it, and the user still won't see it because `v-show` toggles the `display` css property.

Comment: The same problem still occurs though because of the lag introduced by the AJAX load. I simulated that by adding a delay. If you click fast enough on the tour before the ajax load is ready, the intro will appear in the wrong location.

Comment: Okay well now `mounted` is no longer appropriate. You need a variable per item that keeps track of the ajax status. https://jsfiddle.net/eejn7p27/1/. This will start the intro once all ajax is done.